# How to Update Firebase Value Using an HTML Button Value?

Tags: html, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

So I figured out how to update the value of the database, but the another problem came up. When I'm trying to update the value of a certain in the table, the output is that it updated all the values. I'm not getting the correct key when a certain button is pressed for the update. Can you guys help me with this?

My .html file

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("REPORTS").child('05-21-2017');

rootRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot){
var date = snapshot.child("dateAndTime").val();
var lat = snapshot.child("latitude").val();
var long = snapshot.child("longitude").val();
var link = snapshot.child("link").val();
var report = snapshot.child("report").val();
var status = snapshot.child("status").val();
var needs = snapshot.child("needs").val();
var key = snapshot.key;
console.log(key);
var updateData = "updateData()";


$("#table_body").append("<tr id='"+snapshot.key+"'><td>"+snapshot.key+"</td><td>" +date+"</td><td>"+report+"</td><td>"+lat+"</td><td>"+long+"</td><td>"+status+"</td><td>"+needs+"</td><td><button onclick = "+updateData+">update</button></td></tr>");
   });
```

My .js file

```
 function updateData(key) {
 var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("REPORTS").child('05-21-2017');
 rootRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot){
 var rootRef2 = firebase.database().ref().child("REPORTS").child('05-21-2017/'+snapshot.key);
 console.log(rootRef2);
 rootRef2.update({status: "Ongoing"});
 console.log("success");
});
}
```

[Here is what my table looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9IF5.png)

I want to change a particular table when i click the update button. Please help me, badly needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
const ulTable = document.getElementById('tabla');
```

//Create references

```
const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('Users');
```

//Sync table changes

dbRefObject.on('child_added', snap => {

```
var gear = snap.child('Gear').val();
var level = snap.child('Level').val();
var strength = snap.child('Strength').val();

$(ulTable).append("<tr id="+snap.key+"><td>" + gear + "</td><td>" + level + "</td><td>" + strength + "</td></tr>");
```

});  //child_added

dbRefObject.on('child_changed', snap => {

```
var gear = snap.child('Gear').val();
var level = snap.child('Level').val();
var strength = snap.child('Strength').val();

$("#"+snap.key).html("<td>" + gear + "</td><td>" + level + "</td><td>" + strenght + "</td>");
```

});  //child_changed

dbRefObject.on('child_removed', snap => {

```
var gear = snap.child('Gear').val();
var level = snap.child('Level').val();
var strength = snap.child('Strength').val();

$("#"+snap.key).html("<td>" + gear + "</td><td>" + level + "</td><td>" + strenght + "</td>").remove();
```

});

My DB is:

```
Users -> (Gear, Level, Strength)
```